# setConnectTimeout not working in HttpURLConnection using proxy

Tags: java, proxy, java-7, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

Why does this not work sometimes?

```
con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(update).openConnection(proxy));
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
con.setReadTimeout(60000);
con.connect();
```

I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:484)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:482)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:481)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:522)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at app.main(app.java:108)
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because there's something wrong with the proxy

Comment: tried different proxies, many fail after the first or a few connects

Comment: your proxies? or third party proxies?

Comment: third party proxies, they are used to solve some issues in specific countries due to blocking and also some firewalls, I also use them if there is no anonymous connection so I have to use an anonymous proxy. Is this issue due to the nature of public proxies? Why don't they use the connection timeout which I set and lose the connection sometimes? Some proxies are from hidemyass

Comment: Well each proxy is going to have it's own rate/connection limiting policy.  It could be they consider your software as flooding them with requests or making to many.

Comment: so this is legit that they close the connection wile connecting but do not consider the timeout setting? this also happens when I start this the first time, are the proxies/servers experiencing issues due to the high load of current users?

Comment: Like I said, it's up to each individual proxy.  If they're free proxies, well you get what you pay for.  If their paid for look at their terms and conditions.